# GData Java Client not working because Google redirects to localized site

Tags: java, gdata, google-analytics-api

I'm following the documentation at [Google Analytics Data API - Java](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/1.0/gdataJava.html) 
and am getting the `RedirectRequiredException` exception, because Google 
is redirecting me to a local version of the site (www.google.si).

The code:

```
AnalyticsService as = new AnalyticsService("me-myapp-1.0"); 
as.setUserCredentials(username, password); 
AccountFeed accountFeed = as.getFeed( 
    new URL("https://www.google.com/analytics/accounts/default"), 
    AccountFeed.class);
```

The last method call throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.RedirectRequiredException: Found 
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/ 
html;charset=utf-8"> 
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY> 
<H1>302 Moved</H1> 
The document has moved 
<A HREF="http://www.google.si/">here</A>. 
</BODY></HTML> 
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse (GoogleGDataRequest.java:541) 
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse (HttpGDataRequest.java:535) 
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute (HttpGDataRequest.java:514) 
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute (GoogleGDataRequest.java:515) 
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1016) 
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:879) 
        at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:638) 
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:898) 
        at org.kubje.jaka.gapump.App.main(App.java:42)
```

Any ideas?

I've also posted this question to the Analytics API's Google Group, [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-analytics-data-export-api/browse_thread/thread/8b4dc0860af1a030#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL was incorrect. I copied it from the example, which was incorrect.